# Returning of undefined value passing params with router and store into my index (Vue application)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, store

I'm trying to pass a parameter from my Homepage (Exactly is from my component `HomeJumbo.vue` that is inside the homepage). Before I tried this, the guest was able to pass the param without the query with a search bar, so they were able to search for specialties (I'm using Laravel for my backend API), then when they clicked search, it redirected with the param into my index (called `ListDoctorsPage.vue` and inside the index there is an array for selectedSpecialties[], because of my filtering system that allows the guest to select and deselected what doctors they want to filter by specialties

HomePage.vue

```
<template>
    <section class="pt-20 md:pt-22">
        <div class="py-16 px-6 mx-auto max-w-screen-2xl text-center lg:py-48 z-10 relative">
            <h1
                class="mb-8 px-6 lg:px-32 text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight leading-none text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl dark:text-white">
                La salute è la tua priorità, noi ti aiutiamo a trovarne il custode
            </h1>
            <p class="mb-8 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 lg:text-xl sm:px-16 lg:px-48 dark:text-gray-200">
                BDoctors collabora con centinaia di dottori, specializzati in diversi ambiti della medicina. Tutti i dottori
                sono iscritti all'albo,
                hanno una laurea in medicina e una specializzazione in una determinata area.
            </p>
            <form class="w-full max-w-md mx-auto">
                <label for="default-email" class="mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sr-only dark:text-white">Email
                    sign-up</label>
                <div class="relative">
                    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3.5 pointer-events-none">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em"
                            viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!-- Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. -->
                            <path
                                d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40 122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3 0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0 208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 352a144 144 0 1 0 0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <select v-model="selectedSpecialty" class="block w-full p-4 pl-10 text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-full bg-white focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a specialization</option>
                        <option v-for="specialty in specialties" :key="specialty.id">
                            {{ specialty.name }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" @click="handleSearch"
                        class="text-white absolute right-2.5 bottom-2.5 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bd_btn-shadow font-medium rounded-full text-sm px-4 py-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800 bd_btn">
                        Cerca
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <img src="../../assets/wave.svg" alt="wave-breakpoint">
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'HomeJumbo',
    data() {
        return {
            selectedSpecialty: null,  // This will hold the selected specialty id
        };
    },
    methods: {
        handleSearch(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("In HomeJumbo, pushing to router:", this.selectedSpecialty);
            if (this.selectedSpecialty) {
                this.$router.push({ name: 'doctors', params: { specialties: this.selectedSpecialty } });
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        specialties() {
            return this.$store.state.specialtiesContainer; // Accessing specialties from the store
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // If the store does not already have the specialties, fetch them
        if (!this.specialties.length) {
            this.$store.dispatch('getSpecialties');
        }

        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/doctors/', {
            params: {
                specialties: this.selectedSpecialty,
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            // Handle the response and update your component's data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching doctors:', error);
        });
    },
    watch: {
        selectedSpecialty(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log("Previous specialty selected:", oldVal);
            console.log("Current specialty selected:", newVal);
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>@use "../../styles/partials/variables.scss" as *;

section {
    background-color: $neutral-bg;
}
</style>
```

next I stored all myspecialties in the store.js
and to all the passing with the route and store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

export default createStore({
    state: {
        specialty: null,  // Use specialty if you need to store a single specialty.
        specialtiesContainer: [],
        apiSpecialtiesUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/specialties'
    },
    mutations: {
        setSpecialty(state, specialty) {
            state.specialty = specialty;
        },
        SET_SPECIALTIES(state, specialtiesContainer) {
            state.specialtiesContainer = specialtiesContainer;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getSpecialties({ commit, state }) {
            const params = {}

            axios.get(state.apiSpecialtiesUrl, { params }) 
              .then(response => {
                commit('SET_SPECIALTIES', response.data.results)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching specialties:', error)
              })
        },
        getDoctorsBySpecialty({ commit, state }, payload) {
            console.log("In store action, received payload:", payload);
            // rest of your code...
        }
    }
});
```

Note that specialty = is the specialty selected taken from the homejumbo and the specialties container are the specialties from API

Next all rother then my sistem alredy done, in my index (I'm using script composition setup)
I have to push the selected Specialty into `selectedSpecialties` array

```
const users = ref([]);
const specialties = computed(() => store.state.specialtiesContainer);

const selectedSpecialty = ref(route.params.specialties);
const specialtiesFromStore = computed(() => {
    return store.state.specialtiesContainer;
});

console.log("Selected Specialty:", selectedSpecialty.value);
console.log("Specialties from store:", specialtiesFromStore.value);

// If selectedSpecialty is not already in your selectedSpecialties list, add it
if (selectedSpecialty.value && !selectedSpecialties.value.includes(selectedSpecialty.value)) {
    selectedSpecialties.value.push(selectedSpecialty.value);
}
```

so all my system is already done, and I have to push into the array the value for the first speciality selected because the filters will be checked if they are in that array, so the filters will work

right the problem is that the param specialties (which my API is accepting, is not passing (I receive an undefined value)

I tried to console log each state from when the guest selects the specialty to the index:

- Previous specialty selected: null HomeJumbo.vue:84:21
- Current specialty selected: Chirurgia generale HomeJumbo.vue:85:21
- In HomeJumbo, pushing to router: Chirurgia generale HomeJumbo.vue:53:21
- [Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "specialties" when navigating. See https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22 for more details. vue-router.mjs:35:17
- Selected Specialty: undefined ListDoctorsPage.vue:201:9
- Specialties from store: Proxy { : (16) […], : {…} } ListDoctorsPage.vue:202:9
- getUsers invoked with params: Object { page: 1, specialties: "", minRating: null, minReviewCount: null } ListDoctorsPage.vue:240:11

so the problem is that I'm receiving the warning and I think the problem is I'm forgetting something.
as I told before the system is already done, but if the value is undefined, it cannot get pushed into specialtiesSelected array

Comment: The question lacks route definitions. The warning means what it says, the route has no "specialties" param defined